# Insert data into table automatic after 2days

Tags: php

I created table `account` here 5 columns `a/c_no` `date`, `deposit` `withdraw` `balance`. I need to insert data automatic after 2 days with date and value of interest. How to code this?

Comment: Why dont you insert it now and add a insertion date field to know when was it inserted?, on using, then use only values with +2 days old. Dont forget to use a index for that new field.

Comment: make script  for insert data in table account  as your require Then create cron job of 2 day or your require interval then call script on these cron job.

Comment: Are you using MySQL as the database? It has a built-in Event Scheduler that can run queries periodically.

Comment: How to find Event Scheduler on MySQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have make a scheduler kind of thing, that runs on scheduled time and do the assigned task with the specified logic. In linux, cron is there for this purpose.

> Cron Jobs are used for scheduling tasks to run on the server. They're
>   most commonly used for automating system maintenance or
>   administration. However, they are also relevant to web application
>   development. There are many situations when a web application may need
>   certain tasks to run periodically. Today we are going to explore the
>   fundamentals of Cron Jobs.

[Reference](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)